# Cython3 compile python3.6 with mxnet and paho

Tags: python, cython

I want to protect our server codes written in the python for security reason.

Compiling with Cython looks one of the option. But it gives a lot of errors.

app.py has below imports:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import struct
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QByteArray, QDataStream, QFile, QIODevice, QMimeData, Qt, QTextStream )
import mxnet_model
import argparse
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
import glob
import datetime
import time
import json
import pickle , os
from datetime import timedelta
import queue
from threading import Thread
```

Do I have chance to compile code which heavy imports ?

What could be suggestion ?

PS: Is Cython3 also speeding up the code ?

Comment: If it's on a server and presumably has an API, what is even exposed to users as far as the code?

Comment: I also don't understand the tags. Removing some. Unless you're specific about the errors and they point to those libraries, it's unclear how they are relevant.

Comment: Cython can cope fine with imports, so there's no reason why this wouldn't work. I suggest you provide a [mcve]